# Searching for multuple valeus using REGEX

Tags: sql, regex, string, notepad++

I have a big sporadic sql scripts and need to find and replace a few values in it. I am trying to pass my values in REGEX to Notepad++ but I can't seem to make it work. To be more specific, I have around 50 script, each with 5000 lines, and I need to look for a list of values, e.g.  "[dbo].[livesales]" "[dbo].[CreditCards]" in all my scripts separately. I undertand that I need either run this separately against each script or merger them all into one file, but I need the proper REGEX command for it. I need to include square bracket and dots as well.  I end up building this but it doesn't work for me:

```
^(?=.*\b[dbo].[LiveSales]\b)(?=.*\b[dbo].[CreditCards]\b).+$
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkVjH.png)
thanks in advance,

Comment: it'll be more helpful to post some example your SQL scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother using word boundaries, as square brackets in SQL Server are pretty ubiquitous for database object names (e.g. database and column names).  I suggest the following pattern:

```regex
\[dbo\]\.\[(?:LiveSales|CreditCards)\]
```

### Demo

The major changes I have made include not using word boundaries, escaping the `[` and `]` brackets (since square bracket is a regex metacharacter with a special meaning), and also not try to match the entire input.  Presumably you want to find all such occurrences, and so don't bother trying to scope your pattern with `^` and `$`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, It worked like a magic!

Comment: If it worked,  feel free to accept the answer by clicking ✔